# Value for Active Record attribute not getting saved properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the code below, I am trying to set the `popup` variable for the `Company` object, but where it currently is located, it is not getting set when the user hits the submit button on the page where a company object is created.

When I put the line in question before the `if` statement, the popup variable gets set, but because the object hasn't been saved yet, the `@company.id` has been set yet, so that part of the popup string I am trying to create isn't set properly.

Any ideas how to get my popup variable to be set properly?

```
def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
        redirect_to map_path
        flash[:success] = "Company Successfully Added"
        @company.popup = "<h3><a href='companies/#{@company.id}'>#{@company.name}</a></h3>"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it is an attribute

Comment: So, you want to save `popup` value in database?

Comment: Correct. I just can't figure out where to do it properly.

Comment: Any of the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `popup` is a company attribute and if you need to save it, just use `'before_save'`:

```
def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
        redirect_to map_path
        flash[:success] = "Company Successfully Added"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

**Model:**

```
before_save :set_popup_value

private

def set_popup_value
  popup = "<h3><a href='companies/#{self.id}'>#{self.name}</a></h3>"
  #self.update_attributes(:popup => popup)
  self.update_column(:popup => popup)
end
```

else, if you want `'popup'` just to display it and not to save in a database, then you must use `attr_accessor`.

**Model:**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :popup
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
        @company.popup = "<h3><a href='companies/#{@company.id}'>#{@company.name}</a></h3>"
        redirect_to map_path
        flash[:success] = "Company Successfully Added"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I was working with your top solution and there was an issue with referencing the id like @company.id so I just changed it to id. When I did that, it saves to the database properly but there seems to some type of infinite loop happening.

Comment: Oops! I did a mistake. Please see updated answer. You should not give @company.id in Model.

Comment: I am still have issues where this causes some type of infinite loop.

Comment: Ok, you can also do it in `before_save`. So, check my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no, in both cases, before and after save, there seems to be infinite update calls. Im not sure why. The popup attribute is getting set properly though.

Comment: Can you just use `update_column` instead of `update_attributes`?

Comment: I am trying that now. There was no error, but there was just a problem with infinite call backs. I am fairly sure it was because update_attributes calls the save method in one form or another and because of that after save kept calling set_popup_value over and over